# How to check if a list contains a certain element in R

Tags: r, list

I have the following list

```
A = list(c(1,2,3,4), c(5,6,7,8), c(4,6,2,3,1), c(6,2,1,7,12, 15, 16, 10))
A
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 5 6 7 8

[[3]]
[1] 4 6 2 3 1

[[4]]
[1]  6  2  1  7 12 15 16 10
```

I want to check if the element `2` is present each list or not. If it exists, then I need to assign `1` to that corresponding list.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: lapply(A, function(x) 2 %in% x)

Comment: @jasbner, Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@jasbner's comment can be further refined to

```
1 * sapply(A, `%in%`, x = 2)
# [1] 1 0 1 1
```

In this case `sapply` returns a logical vector, and then multiplication by 1 coerces `TRUE` to `1` and `FALSE` to 0. Also, as the syntax is `x %in% table`, we may avoid defining an anonymous function `function(x) 2 %in% x` and instead write as above. Lastly, using `sapply` rather than `lapply` returns a vector rather than a list, which seems to be what you are after.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple version with replacement!

```
lapply(A, function(x) ifelse(x==2,1,x))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map_lgl(A, `%in%`, x = 2) %>% 
    as.integer
#[1] 1 0 1 1
```